# FORK multiple children, then use PIPE with SELECT

Tags: c, posix, fork, named-pipes

I'm trying to understand fork, mkfifo and select.

I fork N children, each child writes his ID to the pipe, the parent reads the IDs from the pipe.

```
    int myPipe = mkfifo("pipe", S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if (myPipe < 0)
        perror("mkfifo: ");
    
    int n = 3;
    pid_t* pids = malloc(n * sizeof(pid_t));
    
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        pids[i] = fork();
        if (pids[i] < 0)
            perror("Fork: ");
    }
    
    fd_set fdMyPipe;
    FD_ZERO(&fdMyPipe);
    FD_SET(myPipe, &fdMyPipe);
                
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (pids[i] == 0) //child
        {
            printf("Child[%d] : I write my ID to the pipe.\n", i);
            write(myPipe, &i, sizeof(i));
        }
        else //parent
        {
            int j;
            for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            {   
                int r = select(myPipe + 1, &fdMyPipe, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                
                if (FD_ISSET(myPipe, &fdMyPipe))
                {
                    int child;
                    read(myPipe, &child, sizeof(&child));
                    printf("Parent : Child[%d]'s ID is %d.\n", child, child);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The output is the following:

```
Child[0] : I write my ID to the pipe.
Child[0] : I write my ID to the pipe.
Child[0] : I write my ID to the pipe.
Child[1] : I write my ID to the pipe.
Child[0] : I write my ID to the pipe.
Child[1] : I write my ID to the pipe.
Child[2] : I write my ID to the pipe.
```

I can't understand why there are 4 zeros, 2 ones and why they are mixed up.

Also, when I hit enter several times, I get the following:

> Parent : Child[10]'s ID is 10.
>
> Parent : Child[10]'s ID is 10.
>
> Parent : Child[10]'s ID is 10.

Why the ID is 10, and why is it always ten?

**EDIT**

Now I get the correct number/order of children.

```
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        pids[i] = fork();
        if (pids[i] < 0)
            perror("Fork: ");
        
        if (pids[i] == 0) //child
        {
            printf("Child[%d] : I write my ID to the pipe.\n", i);
            write(myPipe, &i, sizeof(i));
            return;
        }
        else //parent
        {
            int j;
            for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            {   
                int r = select(myPipe + 1, &fdMyPipe, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                
                if (FD_ISSET(myPipe, &fdMyPipe))
                {
                    int child;
                    read(myPipe, &child, sizeof(child));
                    printf("Parent : Child[%d]'s ID is %d.\n", child, child);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However, the parent still reads some random ID.

> Parent : Child[1426203146]'s ID is 1426203146.
>
> Parent : Child[1426203146]'s ID is 1426203146.

Comment: You're forking inside of the loop, and child processes when i<n-1 are forking as well.

Comment: `myPipe` (the returned value of `mkfifo()`) is not a valid file descriptor. You need to open the named pipe separately to get valid file descriptors. Also, use `_exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)` instead of `return` in children. Add error handling. btw, you don't need `mkfifo`, `select` here [`pipe` and `read` are enough](https://gist.github.com/7623724). `select` would be useful if there were more than one pipe. `mkfifo` would be useful if you needed a filename for the pipe.

Comment: @j-f-sebestian Thank you, I didn't open the pipe.. :)

Comment: I've updated [the code](https://gist.github.com/7623724) to start reading ids before all children are forked using select to avoid blocking , and reap children automatically. It allows large number of child processes (I've tried with 100000 children )